# In LESS, is it possible to get image dimension from the bitmap files?

Tags: less

I found myself hard-coding some image width numbers in my LESS stylesheet.

It is possible to have a LESS function automate this? e.g.

```
@banner-width : image-width("image/banner.png");
```

Comment: Doubt it, but that would certainly be interesting and useful.

Comment: It would be so nice if they would add this to LESS instead of having to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a **javascript** implementation of less (less.js), you could use javascript interpolation between back-ticks and use normal javascript functionality - something like this:

```
@banner-width: ~`function(imguri){var img=new Image(); img.src = imguri; return img.width }('image/banner.png')`;
```

or go further and make reusable mixins.

**LESS:**

```
.width(@img) {
  @width: ~`function(imguri){var img=new Image(); img.src = imguri; return img.width }(@{img})`;
    width: @width;
}
.height(@img) {
  @height: ~`function(imguri){var img=new Image(); img.src = imguri; return img.height }(@{img})`;
    height: @height;
}

.test{
    @src: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
    .width(@src);
    .height(@src);
}
```

the output **CSS:**

```
.test {
  width: 276;
  height: 110;
}
```

which is exactly what it should be for this logo http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif

- **to add the units** you coud then add `unit(@dimension,px)` into the mixins.

Comment: Just a note that this doesn't work with with the LESSC compiler. `Image is undefined`